# Can I use the file:serialize function to save an existdb XML file to a path in my filesystem?

Tags: xml, exist-db

I want to save an XML in my filesystem and I found that the file:serialize function is able to do that. However it is not clear to me from the documentation (http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/file#serialize.3) how this function is used.

Can somebody provide me with an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script will save a document called `mydocument.xml`, which is stored in the eXist-db collection `/db/apps/myapp/data`, onto the file system into `C:\Users\Joe\workspace` (a typical Mac directory is provided as a comment for you to enable; note the difference in slashes between Windows and Mac/Linux).  I'd suggest using an absolute path for the target directory, as the example uses.  You can modify the serialization parameters as documented at http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xquery.xml#serialization (the `file:serialize()` function will take the parameters listed under "Serialization in XQuery 1.0.")

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $source-doc := doc('/db/apps/myapp/data/mydocument.xml')
let $filename := 'mydocument.xml'
let $target-directory := 
    (: Mac :)
    (: '/Users/Joe/workspace/' :)
    (: Windows :)
    'C:\Users\Joe\workspace\'
let $target-path:= 
    (: Construct the full filesystem path for the file :)
    concat($target-directory, $filename)
return 
    file:serialize($source-doc, $target-path, ("omit-xml-declaration=yes", "indent=yes"))
```